# can i use count query when distinct a field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, count, distinct

how can i get count of elements when using distinct a filed in Elasticsearch ? i want get total elements of index when distinct one of field . i can use these codes for search :

```
**POST myIndex/_search**
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "myField": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name’s of my field",
        "size": 10000
      }
    }
  }
.
.
.
}
```

but , I want query similar to :

```
**GET myIndex/_count**
{
 "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "myField": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name’s of my field",
        "size": 10000
      }
    }
  }
.
.
.
}
```

but return error :

```
**{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "request does not support [size]",
        "line" : 2,
        "col" : 3
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "request does not support [size]",
    "line" : 2,
    "col" : 3
  },
  "status" : 400
}**
```

so i interested a solution a bout this problem .

Answer (score 1):

Elastic search only supports approximate Distinct using [cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html)

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "field-name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

values are approximate. Though you can increase precision using  [precision_threshold](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_precision_control)